# What information should be released to characterize a dataset for text classification?

Tags: classification, dataset, natural-language

I am releasing a dataset for text classification. ​What information would a researcher in natural language processing or machine learning may want to have about this dataset?

Here some some information I thought about:

Dataset itself:

- texts, and text ID (the ID makes it easier to refer to a specific text, e.g. it could be inferred from the filename if each text is in a separate file).
- ​labels, and for each label annotator ID + annotation timestamp​

Meta information + superficial descriptive statistics + baselines (ideally with the source code allowing to produce them when applicable): ​

- number of texts
- number of ​different ​​labels​
- explanation on how the dataset is stored (flat files, MySQL database, etc.) and, if needed, what code one has to run to create/download/prepare/etc. the dataset.
- where do the texts come from, and how they were chosen
- how large are the texts (e.g., boxplot of text length expressed in number of tokens, or histogram)
- how diverse the vocabulary is (e.g., simply stating the vocabulary size)
- how imbalanced the data set is, i.e. the percentage of positive samples, for each label
- cooccurrence matrix of labels (i.e., in how many texts both label X and label Y are present) and label correlations.
- instructions given to annotators (e.g., definition for each label)
- tool(s) used to annotate
- how the annotators​ were chosen​, what their backgrounds are (e.g., medical student specialized in orthopedics)
- how many annotations each of the annotators did.
- were annotation disagreements arbitrated, if so how? (e.g., a third annotator with more experience)
- time spend by annotator to annotate each text
- inter-rater agreement a.k.a. inter-annotator agreement ([Cohen's kappa​](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohen%27s_kappa) if each text was labeled by exactly 2 annotators, otherwise [Fleiss' kappa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fleiss%27_kappa%E2%80%8B) is there more than 2 annotators​​, or [Krippendorff's alpha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krippendorff%27s_alpha) if the number of annotators​ is [variable​](http://doi.org/10.1186/s12874-016-0200-9))
- intra-rater agreement a.k.a. intra-annotator agreement (if the same annotator was asked to annotate the same text twice)
- ​what is the precision/recall​/F1-score of each annotator​​ (i.e., human performance metric against which one can directly compare NLP algorithms)
- ​what is the precision/recall​/F1-score of each annotator​​ (i.e., human performance metric against which one can directly compare NLP algorithms)
- whether annotation policies/quality have fluctuated over time
- are there any missing annotations?
- what is the classification performance of some baseline systems?
- what is the official training/validation/test split? (it is best to provide one so that different publications based on the same data set can be more easily compared against)
- Point of contact if willing to answer any questions.​ (e.g., raising issues on the GitHub repository)​
- ​Checksum​ of ​the dataset (not really needed if we place it on GitHub or if we just release some code to construct the dataset from a larger dataset)
- Encoding​ of the texts ​
- Language​(s)​ of the texts, and if there is more than one language, what the language distribution is.
- Example​s​ of ​the data​ (a.k.a. samples)
- License
- price
- ​DOI​
- Name of the dataset

What other information should I release to ​best present the dataset to researchers in natural language processing or machine learning?

---

Example of the dataset for text classification: a set of patient notes annotated with which medical condition(s) the patient has, amongst 10 medical conditions. I.e., each sample has 10 binary labels, annotated by humans.

---

I have crossposted the question at:

- https://redd.it/66mraj
- http://qr.ae/TwK247

Comment: The [Linguistic Data Consortium](https://www.ldc.upenn.edu/) offers many professionally curated corpora. It may be useful to look at the information that they provide with their data sets as a template.

Comment: @G5W thanks, good idea. (I'm not a huge fan of LDC: it is mostly funded with public money, yet most of their datasets are behind paywall.) [Why doesn't the Linguistic Data Consortium release its data sets free of charge?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/14358/2680)

Comment: I understand your issue with LDC. I am only suggesting them as a model of desirable metadata. For example,  a quick look at their catalog shows one item missing from your list: copyright information.

Comment: @G5W and price :-)